# Получение html-кода из браузера с помощью Delphi

Tags: delphi, браузер

Нужно сделать так, чтобы хтмл код который получает браузер, так же и в мемо отображался, например. Т.е. не просто надо получить еще один хтмл код страницы, а именно тот же код, что и в браузере.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Писать прокси
2. Вешать хук на 80-й (или какой там у вас) порт

Comment: а можно подробнее про 2й вариант?

Comment: я в этом не мастер,
но поиск должен рулить,
ключевые слова:
"перехват пакетов через сокет", "перехват http-трафика"

Answer (score 0):

```
Var iDoc: DispHTMLDocument;

iDoc:= WebBrowser1.Document as DispHTMLDocument;
Memo1.Lines.Add(iDoc.body.innerHTML);
```